# Como posso configurar o Git para ignorar alterações triviais (por exemplo, timestamp do arquivo) num arquivo?

Tags: c, git, batch, makefile

O problema que estou enfrentando é o seguinte:

A aplicação em C possui uma opção onde é exibido a data de compilação da aplicação.
Para evitar que o desenvolvedor gere a aplicação com a data anterior ao do dia atual evitamos o uso do comando de pré-processamento **DATE** num arquivo qualquer pois nem sempre ocorre o rebuild, arquivos já compilados não são recompilados.

Então incluímos no script de pre-build um script que simplesmente cria um arquivo com um registro da data atual em um valor de #define. Este arquivo é gerado sempre que há uma nova build.

exemplo do conteúdo do arquivo gerado (data_compilacao.h):

```
#define DATA_COMPILACAO "20/02/19"
```

Se o dia mudar, o #define é alterado.
Caso contrário, o arquivo permanece inalterado exceto pelo timestamp do arquivo.

Quando executo o status do git nesse cenário sem alteração de valor do #define, o arquivo não tem alterações reais - apenas uma atualização do timestamp do arquivo.

Existe a possibilidade de incluir o arquivo no .gitignore porém gostaria de saber se existe uma outra maneira de configurar o Git para ignorar alterações de timestamp do arquivo.

Há uma forma de configurar o git para isso?
Como eu poderia lidar com essa situação?

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Se entendi bem, adicionar o arquivo que é alterado ao `.gitignore` não resolveria seu problema??

Comment: Pode explicar por que existe essa alteração de data e hora no código, por favor? Se você não está alterando o código, ela precisa existir?

Comment: Pelo que tu explicas, esse arquivo deve ser um arquivo gerado por algum script de build - talvez para atribuir versão, ou coisa do tipo. Então, minha recomendação é que todos os arquivos gerados - inclusive esse - fiquem no `.gitignore`

Comment: @GabrielHardoim adicionar o arquivo ao .gitignore evitará que o arquivo seja adicionado ao commit em qualquer situação. O que procuro é uma forma de ignorar alterações com base em alguma forma de regra. Somente alterações importantes que não envolvam alteração no timestamp do arquivo por exemplo.

Comment: @egomesbrandao Existe alteração porque o script de pre-build está configurado para gerar um arquivo contendo a data atual. Foi decidido esta abordagem ao invés de utilizar um comando de pré-processamento como o __DATE__ para evitar que o desenvolvedor que está gerando a build não gere uma aplicação com a data antiga. (pode ocorrer do desenvolvedor não recompilar o arquivo com o __DATE__, entende?)

Comment: Para que serve esse arquivo com o DATE? Para número de versão?

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado Entendo. foi a sugestão do GabrielHardoim também. Irei adotar esta sugestão por enquanto. Vou continuar buscando uma forma de ignorar mudanças de timestamp do arquivo, deve existir alguma forma.

Agradeço a todos os comentários até o momento. ^^

Comment: @egomesbrandao não existe um arquivo com o __DATE__.
O que eu mencionei acima foi que __não__ utilizamos a abordagem de um arquivo contendo __DATE__.

Ao invés disso, utilizamos outra abordagem, o script pre-build cria uma arquivo contendo o #define da data atual. O problema é que mesmo que a data não mude, a data __do arquivo__ fica com um timestamp diferente.

Comment: O que eu quero saber é mais sobre esse processo, qual a finalidade... Por que acho que é uma questão de conceito:
No código fonte, qualquer alteração deve ser registrada, você está alterando o código, mas pelo que estou entendendo essa alteração é irrelevante... Portanto, se ela é irrelevante, por que ocorre? Acho que esse processo de pre-build deve ser mudado. Pode falar mais sobre isso, por favor, para que possamos te ajudar melhor?

Comment: @egomesbrandao Editei a descrição com maiores detalhes do processo. Já levando em conta a sugestão de adicionar o arquivo no .gitignore.

Comment: @WallanRocha não lembro muito bem do tipo Date no C, mas ele não tem o horário, também? Não seria o caro de comparar só a parte de data?
Bom, ainda não entendi muito bem... Mas dando uma sugestão, se a do parágrafo anterior não der certo... 
O build deve ser realizado em um local centralizado, neste local, seria feito o carimbo da versão do binário. Como você usa Git, seria interessante usar o Git version, e com isso não seria mais necessário esse incremento. Isso também se estiver em um processo de integração contínua, as versões que você não usa, ou que não vão para produção joga-se fora.

Comment: @egomesbrandao o __DATE__ não possui hora. Sim, estou inserindo somente a data.
Entendi que o script vai recriar o arquivo mesmo que não mude a data, então sua sugestão é muito válida, vou pesquisar uma maneira de evitar (já no script de pre-build) que seja recriado o arquivo quando não mudar a data. Obrigado pela sugestão, vou mudar o foco da pesquisa para o script, e deixar o git configurado com o .gitignore por enquanto.

Comment: @WallanRocha Dê uma olhada nessa questão: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16244970/10226260 espero que te ajude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `GIT` não considera diferentes *timestamps* como alteração em arquivo. O que ele pode considerar diferente é:

- **final de linha diferente em diferentes sistemas**;
- permissões alteradas no arquivo;
- qualquer outro caractere normalmente não visualizado em editores;

O primeiro item está grifado pois geralmente em boa parte dos casos é o culpado. Num sistema Windows, se usa `CRLF` e *nix `LF`. Mais informações sobre essas diferenças no artigo ["*Newline*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) da Wikipédia (em inglês).

Muitos editores Windows ou trocam automaticamente o `LF` por `CRLF` ou adicionam os dois. Assim, se o código passa de sistema em sistema, começam essas problemas que você está tendo.

### Solução

Você deve estar em um ambiente com vários tipos de SO sendo usados. Assim sendo, execute os passos abaixo para corrigir os problemas de pulo de linha:

1 - No **Windows**, execute:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

2 - No **Linux** ou **Mac**, execute:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

---

**Sugestão de leitura**: "*[Formatting and Whitespace](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration)*", na seção "*core.autocrlf*". Porém o conteúdo está em inglês.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua contribuição. Está ocorrendo esta alteração no formato da quebra de linha de fato, sua sugestão foi muito útil. A sugestão de leitura ajudou bastante também.

Comment: @WallanRocha opa, sem problemas! Se a resposta resolveu seu problema, marque a resposta como solução para fechar a pergunta e ajudar outras pessoas com problemas parecidos! Caso contrário, comente para que possamos alterar e então ver no que podemos ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Vamos lá, andei pesquisando um pouco e vou tentar resumir aqui.

- Primeiro: Criar o arquivo `.gitattributes` na raiz do projeto ou criar o arquivo `attributes` no diretório `.git/info/`. (Pelo o que eu entendi, o primeiro vai poder ser commitado e o outro não)
- Segundo: Adicionar no arquivo criando uma linha que define o filtro.

  Ex: Nos arquivos que terminem com `*.txt` utilizar o filtro de nome 'shazam'.

  ```
   *.txt filter=shazam
  ```
- Terceiro: Setar as configurações no `.gitconfig`.

  ```
   git config filter.shazam.clean "sed '/shazam/g'"
  ```

Sendo assim, execute o comando `git commit -m "Mensagem" --all` para que ele commite o arquivo executando a instrução passada para o `clean`. Essa configuração foi feita localmente, mas você pode usar o `--global`. Além do `clean` tem também o `smudge` mas ainda não entendi a diferença entre eles.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua contribuição. No momento a solução que adotei foi de alterar o script de pre-build para criar o arquivo novamente somente se a data foi alterada, para isso verifiquei no script uma forma de ler o arquivo e obter a informação da data. Não é o mais elegante porém atende. 

Agora com mais tempo vou seguir sua sugestão dos filtros, não entendo 100% e vou partir para a pesquisa. Novamente, muito obrigado.